# How to make sure no two recurring events will overlap

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method) to store calendar events. Basically storing events not as dates, but as a repeating pattern. Suppose i have events that take place every other day starting from today and some events take place every week on tuesday, starting next week.
The problem with this approach is when entering a new event and how to determine, that no two events will overlap. Some events will have a start, repeat interval, but no repeat stop so how do i compare two such events? I don't want a person to enter a recurring event at the same time another one is already happening.
So my question is, how to make sure with this approach that no two events will overlap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Two questions: Do you have performance issues? Do you want to test that that two events will never overlap "forever" or just within a reasonable range like "next year", or "next decade"?

Comment: Which dbms? (Date/time functionality is often dbms specific...)

Comment: Technically i would like to know whether they will never overlap, but if that is not possible i suppose a reasonable time range would work.  I use mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm: how to check intersections of recurring events definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904087/algorithm-how-to-check-intersections-of-recurring-events-definitions)

Comment: I'm not aware of any algebraic solution to when a monthly event will intersect a weekly event; both the varying length of a month and the complexities of leap years interfere too much.  You're going to be forced to project your patterns in to the future (probably easier to do in your app rather than sql, but possible with recursive CTE) and then check for intersections.  But it should probably be noted; any regular event (every n seconds) WILL eventually intersect any repetition involving months - it's WHEN rather than IF.

Comment: The repetitions will be daily: no less than daily interval. It's every n days where n is an integer. n could be 1 or 60 days, whatever. Isn't this then just a problem of finding where two sets will meet? If i have two interval (a = 3 b = 20) sets starting at 0 and each repeats after a certain time, then their first meeting point is where their LCM is (60). Now its when they are shifted in a way that makes this difficult.  I might be completely confused though.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?